# lighttpd url.rewrite to remove part of url

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, replace, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I'm trying to replace a part of my url before before delivering the file.

I call

```
localhost:8080/files/page_home.d41d8.js
```

and would like to modify the call to

```
/files/page_home.js
```

After that the file shall be delivered directly by lighttpd and not be forwareded to the fastcgi backend.

I tried the following:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi", "mod_rewrite" )

url.rewrite = ("^/files/(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))\.(([a-zA-Z0-9]))\.js$" => "/files/$1.js") 


$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/files/" {

fastcgi.server = (
        "/" => ((
                "bin-path" => "/srv/www/cppapp/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapp.exe",
                "bin-environment" => (
                "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" => ""
                ),
                "socket" => "/tmp/cppapp-fastcgi-socket",
#               # only 1 process !
                "max-procs" => 1,
                "check-local" => "disable",
#               "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
                "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable",
        ))
)

}
```

When I'm looking into the log, the part ".d41d8." is not replaced.

Does anyone of you have a tip for replacing that part?

Thank you very much,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

If someone is searching for answer in future: The problem was the regular expression "^/files/(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)).(([a-zA-Z0-9])).js$". The second part was only matching one char / number. The correct version is "^/files/(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)).(([a-zA-Z0-9]**+**)).js$"